# Calling a T-SQL stored procedure with THROW logic from PYODBC rolls back

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I'm running into some stranger behavior from PYODBC. I have a really simple stored procedure in SQL that does the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [schema].[procname]
(
    @severity       VARCHAR(1) = 'I',
    @LogMessage     VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [schema].[table]
            (col1
            ,col2)
        VALUES
            (@severity
            ,@LogMessage
            )

    IF @severity IN ('E','F')
    BEGIN;
        THROW 320000, @msg, 1
    END

END
GO
```

As you can see, whatever is passed to the parameters is simply inserted into a table. Whenever the @severity is 'E' or 'F', it should throw an error (after inserting).

Now this works fine just calling the procedure in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
EXEC [schema].[procname] @severity='E', @LogMessage = 'XYZ'
```

It will return an error, but the record is inserted.

But whenever I call the procedure from PYODBC:

```
pyodbc_cursor.execute(f"EXEC [schema].[procname] @severity='E', @LogMessage = 'XYZ'")
pyodbc_cursor.commit()
```

I only get the error, and the record is NOT inserted.

I can't explain this behavior. Does someone have any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe pyodbc does a rollback when it finds an error ?

Comment: @Zhorov no its not, works with and without the semicolon. Doesn't really do anything.

Comment: @GuidoG Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: I don't know python, but in most languages when an exception occurs, the statements after that statement are not executed. So I guess your `commit()` is not executed when the `.execute()` returns an exception

Comment: @GuidoG i’ve tested and indeed this seems to be the case. Looking for a workaround now. In case anyone knows a solution, would be happy to hear

Comment: There should not be a workaround, this is normal behaviour, when an exception occurs it never should just execute the next line of code. If you want this behaviour then don't throw an exception, but let the procedure give output that you can read and do whatever you need, but never use exceptions / throw to pass information

Comment: @GuidoG This procedure was once set up to abort any operation this procedure is called in when an error would arise. I agree it's far from perfect but its very hard getting rid of this legacy/technical debt while keeping all the other code alive :( Its something our team is working on for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `throw` to pass information back from your stored procedure, if that is what you want then let the procedure return information like this for example

```
IF @severity IN ('E','F')
BEGIN
    --THROW 320000, @msg, 1
    select @msg as result
END
else
begin
    select 'no errors' as result
end
```

and then just read the result of the procedure after calling it.
And then you can still throw an exception in your python code should you whish so

Comment: Completely agree, the thing is the procedure is being used and called from multiple processes including other sql stored procedures and everything is built around this logic. It will be rebuilt in the future. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Python uses `autocommit=false`, so the driver will execute [`SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). This means that the whole batch is inside a transaction by default. When you throw an error it gets rolled back, removing the insert.

Either set `autocommit=true` in the connection settings, or use another method to return error messages.